# AngularJS ngDialog "Error: No module: ngDialog"

Tags: angularjs

Hey guys i got a problem with implementing ngDialog in my current project.
For testing i have created following **working** code:

test.php

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.1.6/ng-dialog.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.1.6/ng-dialog-theme-plain.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.1.6/ng-dialog.min.js"></script>
  <script src="neuejs.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button ng-click="openDialog($event)">Open Me!</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
        <div id="target" ng-click="test()" ng-controller="tt">
      Bilder
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in a seperate neuejs.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngDialog']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ngDialog) {
$scope.openDialog = function($event) {
var dialog = ngDialog.open({
  template: 'templateId',
  scope: $scope,
  controller: 'FileController',
  $event: $event,
  className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain'
});
};
});
```

This works just fine. Exactly what i want.
My existing project has an app.js file with

```
var iMPULS = angular.module('iMPULS', []);
```

and the project works fine as well, but if i want to use ngDialog and change the module to:

```
var iMPULS = angular.module('iMPULS', ['ngDialog']);
```

the whole layout is kind of messed up, no link in my iMPULS.conf work anymore plus i got "Error: No module: ngDialog" concerning to angular.min.js in Firefox-Browserconsole.

How could this be? I just addes the 'ngDialog' to the module in app.js just like in the testfiles above.

Comment: you also add the scripts in the head ? Are you testing localy ?

Comment: your module name ngDialog and injected in the controller ngDialog are same is that correct?

Comment: @ DMCISSOKHO yes i use the same head as in the test.php, i just changed the ng-app and script-src to app.js instead of neuejs.js. Yes i am testing this currently on a Windows maschine with xammp and apache running. All files are in htdocs.

Comment: @ MrJSingh yes, they are the same. I dont even have to use ngDialog in my controller, the whole project stops working as soon as i ad any kind of ngXXX in the angular.module('myapp',['ngXXX']

Comment: Have you tried to load anuglarJS-resource as last element? Why are you using different angularJS-versions in same project?

Comment: @albert just tried to load angularJS-resource as last element, no changes. I tried different versions just for testing, i was kind of desperate and just tried everything...

Comment: Okay, i just rewrote everything from scratch, kept an eye on the import-sources and finally it works! I don't really know where the problem exactly was...